# ¿Como eliminar una cookie en forma correcta al hacer logout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una serie de `cookies` y `sessions` las cuales se crean al momento de hacer login en forma exitosa en una aplicación. Mi duda es ¿Como puedo eliminar estas `cookies` y `session` creadas al momento de hacer logout?

Tengo lo siguiente en un controlador:

```
CookieService.SetCookie(model.mipropiedad, "cookie1"); // se encarga de crear una cookie de nombre cookie1 con el dato que le paso desde mi modelo.
CookieService.SetCookie(model.mipropiedad2, "cookie2");

Session["MiSession"] = model.mipropiedad3
```

¿Sera correcto eliminar estas cookies de la siguiente forma?

```
public static void LogOut()
{
    var mivar = new HttpCookie("cookie1");
    CookieSession.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    CookieSession.Value = string.Empty;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(mivar);
}
```

De ser con este caso, solo estaria eliminando 1 cookie la que tiene nombre cookie1 pero como elimino las demas junto con las session?

Comment: Este... Si vas a eliminar una cookie al cerrar sesión, ¿por qué la usaste?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, como es eso de para que la usaste... ¿?

Comment: Para qué != por qué. Vamos al chat antes que se llene de varios comentarios :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para eliminar las cookies yo lo que haría es recuperarlas y actualizarlas como haces y al final aplicar un `Session.Abandon()`.
Prueba esto

```
for (int i=0; i<Request.Cookies.Count; i++)
{
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(Request.Cookies[i].Name);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    cookie.Value = string.Empty;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
Session.Abandon();
```

Comment: Entonces seria una buena forma de eliminarla con esta linea `cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);`

Comment: Si. Lo que hace es establecer un tiempo de expiración y la cookie se caduca y elimina del navegador

Comment: Utilice el for para recorrerlas, pero se me queda en un loop, nunca termino de salir del for, y eso que solo encuentra 4 cookies. Lo que hice fue crear una clase un dentro un metodo static donde coloque el for, sera por que mi metodo es static?¿

Comment: Yo tambien probé el bucle de repetición y se quedo en un loop infinito, debido a que esta añadiendo la cookie por lo que aumenta la cuenta de cookies. Esta mal este algoritmo.